# How to join tar files after splitting when we want to join specific files

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, tar

We have the following combination of binaries files (they are after splitting)

```
HADOOPa
HADDOPb
HADOOPc
HADDOPd
HADOOPe
HADDOPf
HADOOPab
HADOOPac
HADOOPbc
```

Now we want to join them to tar. Since we have also other files that start with `HADOOP`, they must be excluded; for example

```
HADOOP-3235.tar
HADOOP_cluster.txt
```

So we need to join only the `HADOOP[a-z]` files to tar.

I'm thinking of doing the following:

```
cat HADOOP{a..z} > HADOOP.tar.gz
```

Is this approach, with the irregular expression, valid?

Comment: Are you asking “how do I add files to a tar archive?”? OR asking about how to join a file that was cut into many bits (i.e. append one after another: concatenate)? OR something else?

Comment: I am asking about Join binaries with different names to tar.gz file and exclude other files that start with the same name  , see my example in my question

Comment: This question is unclear, even with the comment (that should be incorporated into the question). Ensure that all parts of the question ask the same think, including the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{a..z}` is a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), and it’s probably not quite what you want: it will expand to all characters from `a` to `z`, without considering whether a corresponding file exists. You should use the `HADOOP[a-z]` [glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) instead, since that will expand only to file names which correspond to files on disk:

```
cat HADOOP[a-z] > HADOOP.tar.gz
```

If you have more than 26 split files, you can repeat `[a-z]`:

```
cat HADOOP[a-z][a-z] > HADOOP.tar.gz
```

You can be more precise by adding more globs; for example, if you have 80 files:

```
cat HADOOP[a-z] HADOOP[a-b][a-z] HADOOPc[a-d] > HADOOP.tar.gz
```

Comment: by the way what in case we have HADOOPab HADOOPac ? , cat HADOOP[a-z] also fit for that?

Comment: @yael then put that in your question, which clearly said, "_need to join only the `HADOOP[a-z]` files_". If you didn't mean _only_ then don't write it.

Comment: I update the question - sorry

Comment: Your question still says “so need to join only the `HADOOP[a-z]` files to tar”. You can repeat `[a-z]` as many times as necessary.